# How to add `map` operator in subscribe

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

In my component, I am getting the events from parent. ( wrapper ) But before i send to template, I require to iterate and add the date value in the array. not works for me after i do this with subscribe.

any one show me the correct way to re-assign the value after do the iteration?

here is my try:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarService } from "./../../services/calendar.service";
import { ModelEvent, EventState } from "./../../models/model.event";
import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';
import { colors } from "./../../utilities/colors";
import { setHours, setMinutes, setDate } from 'date-fns';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'ibo-calendar',
    templateUrl: './ibo-calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ibo-calendar.component.scss']
})
export class IboCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

    // events = [];
    eventId:number | null;

    view: string = 'month';
    // viewDate: Date = new Date('August 19, 2018');
    viewDate: Date = new Date()

    @Input() events:Observable<ModelEvent[]>;
    @Input() currentEvent: ModelEvent;

    clickedDate: Date;
    updatedEvents:Observable<ModelEvent[]>;

    constructor(private calendarService:CalendarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.updatedEvents = this.events.subscribe(events => {
            console.log('events', events); //getting consoled.
            return map(event => { //not works!!
                return {
                    title : event.title,
                    name : event.name,
                    date : new Date()
                }
            })
        })

}
```

Comment: You should map your data before you subscribe.

Comment: You mean to map in the wrapper component?

Comment: @3gwebtrain no, in the `pipe()` part of your observable, written `events.pipe(map(..)).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For RxJS >= 6**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

try:

```
    this.updatedEvents = this.events.pipe(map(event => {
            return {
                title : event.title,
                name : event.name,
                date : new Date()
            }
        })).subscribe(events => {
           console.log(events)
        })
    })
```

or you can do:

```
    this.updatedEvents = this.events.subscribe(events => {
        this.some_val_to_render_on_html = events.map(event => 
            return {
                title : event.title,
                name : event.name,
                date : new Date()
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: getting error as `this.events.subscribe is not a function`

Comment: @3gwebtrain : for example 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the map operator before subscribe. see below updated code.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; 

 ngOnInit() {

    this.updatedEvents = this.events.pipe(map(event => { 
            return {
                title : event.title,
                name : event.name,
                date : new Date()
            }).subscribe(events => {
                  console.log('events', events);

        })
    })
```

Hope this help!

Comment: @ThePram - getting error as `src/app/calendar/components/ibo-calendar/ibo-calendar.component.ts(46,31): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/calendar/components/ibo-calendar/ibo-calendar.component.ts(47,11): error TS1005: ':' expected.`

Answer (score 0):

Map works on array, you should try to use "events.map"

```
 this.updatedEvents = this.events.subscribe(events => {
        console.log('events', events); //getting consoled.
        return events.map(event => {
            return {
                title : event.title,
                name : event.name,
                date : new Date()
            }
        })
    })
```

Note: map is replaced by events.map

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't change the value of the observable inside the subscribe method. The only thing you can do inside the subscribe is to **use** the value in some way.

instead if you want to change the value of the observable you need to use the **map** operator.

In the example below, we use two different functions called map: one is an rxjs operator, we use it to change the value inside the observable. The other is an array function which is native to javascript. We use it to change **each item** of the array.

I used spread syntax here (...) because I think you mind find it useful.

```
 this.updatedEvents = this.events.pipe(
    map((eventArr) => {
            return eventArr.map((event) => {
                ...event,
                date : new Date()
            })
        }));
```